# Session after redirct (other site) seems disappeared

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I'm implementing paypal payment on my website.
Now, when a user logs in, clicks on the paypal payment link, does the payment, Paypal redirect him again to the user zone. The problem is that session data seem disappeared.

How can I mantain the session data alive, during the absence of the user?

Comment: For how long does it absent? What is the session timeout setting?

Comment: Are you redirecting the user to the correct domain? Remember, `domain.com` != `www.domain.com`

Comment: @Pekka, your were right in the first comment. Thanks for the tip ;) If you write an answer, I'll give you accepted mark.

Comment: @Pekka: super friday-fueled guessing power!

Comment: No problem. I could post it as an answer, but you can also delete your question, seeing as it seems to be attracting downvotes... unfairly I think, but well. @zerkms yeah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you redirect to a URL with the 100% right domain.

Remember, `domain.com` is not the same as `www.domain.com` and a session started on the latter will not be present on the other.

The same applies to protocols: a session started on a `http://` URL won't carry forward to `https://`.